# Swift API URLSession will not append strings to my local string array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, urlsession

I have built an app that pulls recipes from an api using a URLsession datatask. It then takes all recipe names and stores them in an array of strings. Nothing nested, just recipe names. I have a custom func to achieve this. When I call said function it appends perfectly to my global array however when the URLSession datatask completes, the array reverts back and appears untouched. How do I keep this from happening?

Here is how I declare my vars

```
class RecipesVCTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var testArray=[String]()
    
    @IBOutlet var TV: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // where the problem is taking place
        testXcode()
        
        // refresh and reload table view cells
        TV.reloadData()
        
        //for debugging/breakpoints
        print()
    }
```

Here is my custom api pull func that is trying to append to testArray:[String]

```
func testXcode(){
        
        let apiURL = URL(string: "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=mexican&app_id=MYID&app_key=MYAPIKEY")!
        
        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: apiURL) { (data, response, error) in
            let top = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
            
            let middle = top["hits"] as? [[String:Any]]
            
            for each in middle!{
                
                // try to append string to string array using hardcode for now
                self.testArray.append("Hard code test string.")
                    
                self.TV.reloadData()
            }
            
        }
        
        session.resume()
    }
```

I removed my apiKey/ID for security reasons. It is still within my app.

Comment: How does the doc say you should return data?

Comment: the api returns a [String:Any] dictionary. That pulls perfect and my debugger shows good data. I just cant keep what I append to stick. Thats the reason Im trying to append a hard coded string. Once the data sticks, I will append the API data instead of hard code vals.

Comment: How does the DOC say you should return data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checking the value from the `print()` in `viewDidLoad()` function then `testArray` will be the same because `dataTask`'s `completionHandler` has not been called yet. you should check the value in the `completionHandler` like below.

```
class RecipesVCTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var testArray=[String]()

@IBOutlet var TV: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // where the problem is taking place
    testXcode()
    
}

func testXcode() {
    let apiURL = URL(string: "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=mexican&app_id=MYID&app_key=MYAPIKEY")!
    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: apiURL) { (data, response, error) in
        let top = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
        
        let middle = top["hits"] as? [[String:Any]]
        
        for each in middle!{
            // try to append string to string array using hardcode for now
            self.testArray.append("Hard code test string.")
        }
        self.TV.reloadData()
        
        // Check it from here
        print()
    }
    
    session.resume()
}
```

}

Comment: Remember to dispatch `TV.reloadData` back to the main queue. Model updates should really go on the main queue, too.

Comment: What @Rob saying is absolutely correct, I was not paying attention to anything else other than pointing you out why `testArray` is not changed.

Comment: Everything runs and works perfect! Thank you so much for pointing out what I did incorrect!